# they're gone/they've gone/they've left

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language, sentence-choice

1. Someone came, so I hid. I think they're gone now.
2. Someone came, so I hid. I think they've gone now.
3. Someone came, so I hid. I think they've left now.

Do all these sound natural? Which is the more natural one in the context?

Answer (score 1):

(2) is the most natural. If you saw someone's presence as a threat, it would be more idiomatic to say 'they've gone' than 'they've left'.

*They are gone* would have been acceptable two or three centuries ago, but is now archaic.

Comment: +1 Good answer. It's also important to point out "be gone" sounds like they are dead. So yes out of context, (2) is the most natural.

Comment: @AlexTheBN - To 'be gone' _can_ mean to be dead, but that isn't necessarily the primary meaning.

Answer (score -1):

All three of these sound natural to me. As for which is most natural, I would rank them as 3 sounding the most natural, 1 the second most natural, and 2 the least natural. They all sound natural though, so if you were to use any one of these three it would sound fine.